# CMYK shadings implementation for PGF

Tags: graphics, pdf, tex

[PGF](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) is a graphics framework for \$\TeX\$ and friends. It supports shadings (gradients), but only in RGB.

There is often a need to output shadings in CMYK and I am having a go at implementing this.

I'm looking for feedback from those who know PGF well as to whether my strategy is good or not and what things I might not have considered.

At present, only axial and radial shadings are supported (not functional ones).

The package is for *\$\LaTeX\$, not ConTeXt or Plain \$\TeX\$.

And not all backends are supported (only `pdftex`, `luatex`, `xetex`, and `dvipdfmx`).

This code is currently implemented as a separate package to `pgf`, but could possibly be included in the main package in the future.

The code is hosted on GitHub at [https://github.com/dcpurton/pgf-cmykshadings](https://github.com/dcpurton/pgf-cmykshadings/tree/52bf22b3f770415bc9b66913307e17155fad835f)

## Main style file (`pgf-cmykshadings.sty`)

```tex
\ProvidesPackage{pgf-cmykshadings}[2018/10/08 CMYK shadings support for PGF (DCP)]

\RequirePackage{pgf}


% macros from pgfcoreshade.code.tex
\def\pgf@parsefunccmyk#1{%
  \edef\temp{{#1}}%
  \expandafter\pgf@convertcmykstring\temp%
  \edef\temp{{\pgf@cmykconv}}%
  \expandafter\pgf@@parsefunccmyk\temp}

\def\pgf@@parsefunccmyk#1{%
  \let\pgf@bounds=\pgfutil@empty%
  \let\pgf@funcs=\pgfutil@empty%
  \let\pgf@psfuncs=\pgfutil@empty%
  \let\pgf@encode=\pgfutil@empty%
  \let\pgf@sys@shading@ranges=\pgfutil@empty%
  \pgf@sys@shading@range@num=0\relax%
  \pgf@parsefirstcmyk[#1; ]%
  \pgf@parselastdomcmyk[#1; ]%
  \pgf@parsemidcmyk[#1; ]%
  \ifx\pgf@bounds\pgfutil@empty%
    \edef\pgf@pdfparseddomain{0 1}%
    \edef\pgf@pdfparsedfunction{\pgf@singlefunc\space}%
  \else%
    \edef\pgf@pdfparseddomain{\pgf@doma\space\pgf@domb}%
    \edef\pgf@pdfparsedfunction{%
      << /FunctionType 3 /Domain [\pgf@doma\space\pgf@domb] /Functions
      [\pgf@funcs\space] /Bounds [\pgf@bounds] /Encode [0 1 \pgf@encode]
      >> }% <<
  \fi%
  \xdef\pgf@psfuncs{\pgf@psfuncs}%
  }

\def\pgf@parsefirstcmyk[cmyk(#1)=(#2,#3,#4,#5)#6]{%
  \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{#1}%
  \edef\pgf@sys@shading@start@pos{\the\pgf@x}%
  \pgf@sys@bp@correct\pgf@x%
  \edef\pgf@doma{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@x}}%
  \edef\pgf@prevx{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@x}}%
  \pgf@getcmyktuplewithmixin{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
  \edef\pgf@sys@shading@start@cmyk{\pgf@sys@cmyk}%
  \let\pgf@sys@prevcolor=\pgf@sys@shading@start@cmyk%
  \let\pgf@sys@prevpos=\pgf@sys@shading@start@pos%
  \edef\pgf@prevcolor{\pgf@cmyk}%
  \edef\pgf@firstcolor{\pgf@cmyk}}

\def\pgf@parselastdomcmyk[cmyk(#1)=(#2,#3,#4,#5); {%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar]{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{#1}%
    \edef\pgf@sys@shading@end@pos{\the\pgf@x}%
    \pgf@max=\pgf@x\relax%
    \pgf@sys@bp@correct\pgf@x%
    \edef\pgf@domb{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@x}}%
    \pgf@getcmyktuplewithmixin{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
    \edef\pgf@sys@shading@end@cmyk{\pgf@sys@cmyk}%
    \pgfutil@gobble}{\pgf@parselastdomcmyk[}}

\def\pgf@parsemidcmyk[cmyk(#1)=(#2,#3,#4,#5); {\pgf@parserestcmyk[}

\def\pgf@parserestcmyk[cmyk(#1)=(#2,#3,#4,#5); {%
  \advance\pgf@sys@shading@range@num by1\relax%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar]{%
    \pgf@getcmyktuplewithmixin{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
    \edef\pgf@singlefunc{\space%
      << /FunctionType 2 /Domain [0 1] /C0
      [\pgf@prevcolor] /C1 [\pgf@cmyk] /N 1 >> }% <<
    \edef\pgf@funcs{\pgf@funcs\space%
      << /FunctionType 2 /Domain [\pgf@doma\space\pgf@domb] /C0
      [\pgf@prevcolor] /C1 [\pgf@cmyk] /N 1 >> }% <<
    \edef\pgf@psfuncs{\pgf@prevx\space \pgf@cmyk\space \pgf@prevcolor\space pgfshade \pgf@psfuncs}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{#1}%
    \edef\pgf@sys@shading@ranges{\pgf@sys@shading@ranges{{\pgf@sys@prevpos}{\the\pgf@x}{\pgf@sys@prevcolor}{\pgf@sys@cmyk}}}%
    \edef\pgf@sys@prevpos{\the\pgf@x}%
    \let\pgf@sys@prevcolor=\pgf@sys@cmyk%
    \pgfutil@gobble}{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{#1}%
    \pgf@getcmyktuplewithmixin{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
    \edef\pgf@sys@shading@ranges{\pgf@sys@shading@ranges{{\pgf@sys@prevpos}{\the\pgf@x}{\pgf@sys@prevcolor}{\pgf@sys@cmyk}}}%
    \edef\pgf@sys@prevpos{\the\pgf@x}%
    \let\pgf@sys@prevcolor=\pgf@sys@cmyk%
    \edef\pgf@psfuncs{\pgf@prevx\space \pgf@cmyk\space \pgf@prevcolor\space pgfshade \pgf@psfuncs}%
    \pgf@sys@bp@correct\pgf@x%
    \edef\pgf@prevx{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@x}}%
    \edef\pgf@bounds{\pgf@bounds\space\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@x}}%
    \edef\pgf@encode{\pgf@encode\space0 1}%
    \edef\pgf@singlefunc{\space%
      << /FunctionType 2 /Domain [0 1] /C0
      [\pgf@prevcolor] /C1 [\pgf@cmyk] /N 1 >> }% <<
    \edef\pgf@funcs{\pgf@funcs\space%
      << /FunctionType 2 /Domain [\pgf@doma\space\pgf@domb] /C0
      [\pgf@prevcolor] /C1 [\pgf@cmyk] /N 1 >> }% <<
    \edef\pgf@prevcolor{\pgf@cmyk}%
    \pgf@parserestcmyk[}}

\def\pgf@getcmyktuplewithmixin#1#2#3#4{%
  \pgfutil@definecolor{pgfshadetemp}{cmyk}{#1,#2,#3,#4}%
  \pgfutil@ifundefined{applycolormixins}{}{\applycolormixins{pgfshadetemp}}%
  \pgfutil@extractcolorspec{pgfshadetemp}{\pgf@tempcolor}%
  \expandafter\pgfutil@convertcolorspec\pgf@tempcolor{cmyk}{\pgf@cmykcolor}%
  \expandafter\pgf@getcmyk@@\pgf@cmykcolor!}

\def\pgf@getcmyk@@#1,#2,#3,#4!{%
  \def\pgf@cmyk{#1 #2 #3 #4}%
  \def\pgf@sys@cmyk{{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}

\def\pgf@convertcmykstring#1{%
  \def\pgf@cmykconv{}%
  \pgf@converttocmyk#1]%
  }

\def\pgf@converttocmyk{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar]{\pgfutil@gobble}%done!
  {%
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar;{\pgf@grabsemicolorcmyk}%
    {%
      \pgfutil@ifnextchar c{\pgf@gobblec}%
      {%
        \pgfutil@ifnextchar g{\pgf@grabgraycmyk}%
        {%
          \pgfutil@ifnextchar o{\pgf@grabcolorcmyk}%
          {%
            \pgfutil@ifnextchar m{\pgf@grabcmyk}%
            {%
              \pgfutil@ifnextchar r{\pgf@grabrgbcmyk}%
                {\pgferror{Illformed shading
                 specification}\pgf@converttocmyk}%
            }%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\def\pgf@grabsemicolorcmyk;{%
  \edef\pgf@cmykconv{\pgf@cmykconv; }\pgf@converttocmyk}

\def\pgf@gobblec c{\pgf@converttocmyk}

\def\pgf@grabrgbcmyk rgb(#1)=(#2,#3,#4){%
  \pgfutil@definecolor{pgf@tempcol}{rgb}{#2,#3,#4}%
  \pgfutil@extractcolorspec{pgf@tempcol}{\pgf@tempcolor}%
  \expandafter\pgfutil@convertcolorspec\pgf@tempcolor{cmyk}{\pgf@cmykcolor}%
  \expandafter\pgf@convgetcmyk@\expandafter{\pgf@cmykcolor}{#1}%
}

\def\pgf@grabcmyk myk(#1)=(#2,#3,#4,#5){%
  \edef\pgf@cmykconv{\pgf@cmykconv cmyk(#1)=(#2,#3,#4,#5)}\pgf@converttocmyk}

\def\pgf@grabgraycmyk gray(#1)=(#2){%
  \edef\pgf@cmykconv{\pgf@cmykconv cmyk(#1)=(0,0,0,#2)}\pgf@converttocmyk}

\def\pgf@grabcolorcmyk olor(#1)=(#2){%
  \pgfutil@colorlet{pgf@tempcol}{#2}%
  \pgfutil@extractcolorspec{pgf@tempcol}{\pgf@tempcolor}%
  \expandafter\pgfutil@convertcolorspec\pgf@tempcolor{cmyk}{\pgf@cmykcolor}%
  \expandafter\pgf@convgetcmyk@\expandafter{\pgf@cmykcolor}{#1}%
}

\def\pgf@convgetcmyk@#1#2{%
  \edef\pgf@cmykconv{\pgf@cmykconv cmyk(#2)=(#1)}\pgf@converttocmyk}

\def\pgfdeclarehorizontalcmykshading{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[\pgf@declarehorizontalcmykshading{\pgf@declarehorizontalcmykshading[]}}%
\def\pgf@declarehorizontalcmykshading[#1]#2#3#4{%
  \expandafter\def\csname pgf@deps@pgfshading#2!\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@deps@pgfshading#2!\endcsname\pgfutil@empty%
    \pgfsys@horicmykshading{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \else%
    \expandafter\def\csname pgf@func@pgfshading#2!\endcsname{\pgfsys@horicmykshading}%
    \expandafter\def\csname pgf@args@pgfshading#2!\endcsname{{#3}{#4}}%
    \expandafter\let\csname @pgfshading#2!\endcsname=\pgfutil@empty%
  \fi}

\def\pgfdeclareverticalcmykshading{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[\pgf@declareverticalcmykshading{\pgf@declareverticalcmykshading[]}}%
\def\pgf@declareverticalcmykshading[#1]#2#3#4{%
  \expandafter\def\csname pgf@deps@pgfshading#2!\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@deps@pgfshading#2!\endcsname\pgfutil@empty%
    \pgfsys@vertcmykshading{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \else%
    \expandafter\def\csname pgf@func@pgfshading#2!\endcsname{\pgfsys@vertcmykshading}%
    \expandafter\def\csname pgf@args@pgfshading#2!\endcsname{{#3}{#4}}%
    \expandafter\let\csname @pgfshading#2!\endcsname=\pgfutil@empty%
  \fi}

\def\pgfdeclareradialcmykshading{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[\pgf@declareradialcmykshading{\pgf@declareradialcmykshading[]}}%
\def\pgf@declareradialcmykshading[#1]#2#3#4{%
  \expandafter\def\csname pgf@deps@pgfshading#2!\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@deps@pgfshading#2!\endcsname\pgfutil@empty%
    \pgfsys@radialcmykshading{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \else%
    \expandafter\def\csname pgf@func@pgfshading#2!\endcsname{\pgfsys@radialcmykshading}%
    \expandafter\def\csname pgf@args@pgfshading#2!\endcsname{{#3}{#4}}%
    \expandafter\let\csname @pgfshading#2!\endcsname=\pgfutil@empty%
  \fi}


\def\pgfusecmykshading#1{%
  \edef\pgf@shadingname{@pgfshading#1}%
  \pgf@tryextensions{\pgf@shadingname}{\pgfalternateextension}%
  \expandafter\pgfutil@ifundefined\expandafter{\pgf@shadingname}%
  {\pgferror{Undefined shading "#1"}}%
  {%
    {%
      \pgfutil@globalcolorsfalse%
      \def\pgf@shade@adds{}%
      \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@deps\pgf@shadingname}%
      {}%
      {%
        \edef\@list{\csname pgf@deps\pgf@shadingname\endcsname}%
        \pgfutil@for\@temp:=\@list\do{%
          {%
            \pgfutil@ifundefined{applycolormixins}{}{\applycolormixins{\@temp}}%
            \pgfutil@extractcolorspec{\@temp}{\pgf@tempcolor}%
            \expandafter\pgfutil@convertcolorspec\pgf@tempcolor{cmyk}{\pgf@cmykcolor}%
            \xdef\pgf@shade@adds{\pgf@shade@adds,\pgf@cmykcolor}%
          }%
        }%
      }%
      \expandafter\pgf@strip@shadename\pgf@shadingname!!%
      \pgfutil@ifundefined{@pgfshading\pgf@basename\pgf@shade@adds!}%
      {%
        {%
          \expandafter\def\expandafter\@temp\expandafter{\csname pgf@func\pgf@shadingname\endcsname}%
          \edef\@args{{\pgf@basename\pgf@shade@adds}}%
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def%
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@@args%
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname pgf@args\pgf@shadingname\endcsname}%
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@temp\expandafter\@args\@@args%
          %
        }%
      }%
      {}%
      \pgf@invokeshading{\csname @pgfshading\pgf@basename\pgf@shade@adds!\endcsname}%
    }%
  }%
}


% load the correct driver

\def\pgfutilgetcmykshadingsdriver{%
  \expandafter\pgfutil@getcmykshadingsdriver\pgfsysdriver[
}
\def\pgfutil@getcmykshadingsdriver pgfsys-#1[{%
  \edef\pgfsyscmykshadingsdriver{pgfsys-cmykshadings-#1}%
}

\pgfutilgetcmykshadingsdriver

\input\pgfsyscmykshadingsdriver


% style options to make use CMYK gradients by default or not

\let\pgfdeclarehorizontalrgbshading\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading
\let\pgfdeclareverticalrgbshading\pgfdeclareverticalshading
\let\pgfdeclareradialrgbshading\pgfdeclareradialshading
\let\pgfusergbshading\pgfuseshading

\DeclareOption{default}{%
  \let\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading\pgfdeclarehorizontalcmykshading
  \let\pgfdeclareverticalshading\pgfdeclareverticalcmykshading
  \let\pgfdeclareradialshading\pgfdeclareradialcmykshading
  \let\pgfuseshading\pgfusecmykshading
}

\DeclareOption{nodefault}{%
  \let\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading\pgfdeclarehorizontalrgbshading
  \let\pgfdeclareverticalshading\pgfdeclareverticalrgbshading
  \let\pgfdeclareradialshading\pgfdeclareradialrgbshading
  \let\pgfuseshading\pgfusergbshading
}

\ExecuteOptions{default}

\ProcessOptions\relax
```

## `pdftex` driver (`pgfsys-cmykshadings-pdftex.def`)

Other drivers are analogous.

```tex
\ProvidesFile{pgfsys-cmykshadings-pdftex.def}[2018/10/08 CMYK shadings support for PGF pdftex driver (DCP)]

\def\pgfsys@horicmykshading#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \pgf@parsefunccmyk{#3}%
    \pgfmathparse{#2}%
    \setbox\pgfutil@tempboxa=\hbox to\pgf@max{\vbox to\pgfmathresult pt{\vfil\pgfsys@invoke{/Sh sh}}\hfil}%
    \pgf@process{\pgfpoint{\pgf@max}{#2}}%
    \immediate\pdfxform resources {%
      /Shading << /Sh << /ShadingType 2
      /ColorSpace /DeviceCMYK
      /Domain [\pgf@pdfparseddomain]
      /Coords [\pgf@doma\space0 \pgf@domb\space0]
      /Function \pgf@pdfparsedfunction
      /Extend [false false] >> >>}\pgfutil@tempboxa% <<
    \expandafter\xdef\csname @pgfshading#1!\endcsname{\leavevmode\noexpand\pdfrefxform\the\pdflastxform}% 
  }%
}

\def\pgfsys@vertcmykshading#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \pgf@parsefunccmyk{#3}%
    \pgfmathparse{#2}%
    \setbox\pgfutil@tempboxa=\hbox to\pgfmathresult pt{\vbox to\pgf@max{\vfil\pgfsys@invoke{/Sh sh}}\hfil}%
    \pgf@process{\pgfpoint{#2}{\pgf@max}}%
    \immediate\pdfxform resources {%
      /Shading << /Sh << /ShadingType 2
      /ColorSpace /DeviceCMYK
      /Domain [\pgf@pdfparseddomain]
      /Coords [0 \pgf@doma\space0 \pgf@domb]
      /Function \pgf@pdfparsedfunction
      /Extend [false false] >> >>}\pgfutil@tempboxa% <<
    \expandafter\xdef\csname @pgfshading#1!\endcsname{\leavevmode\noexpand\pdfrefxform\the\pdflastxform}%
  }%
}

\def\pgfsys@radialcmykshading#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \pgf@parsefunccmyk{#3}%
    \setbox\pgfutil@tempboxa=\hbox to2\pgf@max{\vbox to2\pgf@max{\vfil\pgfsys@invoke{/Sh sh}}\hfil}%
    \pgf@process{#2}%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \pgf@process{\pgfpoint{\pgf@max}{\pgf@max}}%
    \advance\pgf@xa by \pgf@x%
    \advance\pgf@ya by \pgf@y%
    \pgf@sys@bp@correct{\pgf@x}%
    \pgf@sys@bp@correct{\pgf@y}%
    \pgf@sys@bp@correct{\pgf@xa}%
    \pgf@sys@bp@correct{\pgf@ya}%
    \immediate\pdfxform resources {%
      /Shading << /Sh << /ShadingType 3
      /ColorSpace /DeviceCMYK
      /Domain [\pgf@pdfparseddomain]
      /Coords [\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@xa} \pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@ya} \pgf@doma\space \pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@x} \pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@y} \pgf@domb]
      /Function \pgf@pdfparsedfunction
      /Extend [true false] >> >>}\pgfutil@tempboxa% <<
    \expandafter\xdef\csname @pgfshading#1!\endcsname{\leavevmode\noexpand\pdfrefxform\the\pdflastxform}%
  }%
}

\endinput
```

Comment: @200_success, perhaps this site is not suitable for my question then. I can post the code, but my question is mainly about whether my method of integrating my code with the *very* large code base of `pgf` is the right way to go about things. To answer this, the reviewer would need to be reasonably familiar with PGF.

Comment: You don't even have that much code in your repository.  You could totally paste all of your code here.

Comment: We got a character limit on questions of over 60k. Your code fits just fine, thank you for including it.